# How can I preload association and get it returned in ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Let say I have a `User` model which `has_many` `Post`.

I fetched a user:

```
user = Repo.get(User, 1)
```

and now I want to get all posts for this user. The only solution I found is to:

```
posts = Repo.preload(user, :posts).posts
```

But it's ugly. Is there any shorthand for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Ecto.assoc/2` to get a query for all the posts and then pass that to `Repo.all/1` to actually fetch them:

```
iex(1)> user = Repo.get(User, 1)
iex(2)> Ecto.assoc(user, :posts)
#Ecto.Query<from p in MyApp.Post, where: p.user_id == ^1>
iex(3)> Ecto.assoc(user, :posts) |> Repo.all
[debug] QUERY OK source="posts" db=2.4ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."user_id", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (p0."user_id" = $1) [1]
...
```

Comment: What's the difference between `assoc` and `preload` ?

Comment: `assoc` builds a query for particular association without retrieving data from db, `preload` retrieves data from db for association including nested associations.

Comment: Note that `preload/2` returns both the parent record (user in this case) and the associated records (posts) in one data structure, while `assoc/2` piped to `Repo.all` only returns the associated records (posts). This means if you need the parent record, you can `get` them separately (as in the example above) but  you won't have that data if you write it entirely as piped statements.

Comment: In case the association was already loaded, `Repo.preload/2` won't attempt to reload it.

Answer (score 15):

```
user = Repo.get(User, 1) |> Repo.preload([:posts])
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.

Answer (score 4):

```
user = Repo.get(User, 1) |> preload(:posts)
```

Is the shorthand for your case